# How to use Ack in RabbitMQ for C#?

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, ack

I am using RabbitMQ to get some messages in a queue. One by One.
This is a snippet of my code:

```
   var data = channel.BasicGet(queue, true);
        if (data != null)
            message = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data.Body);
        else
            message = "";
        return message;
```

But i would like to know how to use the Ack property? How can i confirm/cancel the message that was read?

Thanx!

Comment: Have you [read the documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/dotnet-api-guide.html)?  The second parameter of `BasicGet` indicates whether to automatically acknowledge.  If you set it to `false` then you can call `channel.BasicAck` to acknowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the Docs](https://www.rabbitmq.com/dotnet-api-guide.html):

> Since noAck = false above, you must also call IModel.BasicAck to acknowledge that you have successfully received and processed the message:

i.e. you have two different options with `BasicGet`

**With `noAck` true**

```
channel.BasicGet(queue, true);
```

This way, you don't need to ack the message - the message will be removed from the queue after the `BasicGet`. This usage is typically for low-value messages - if processing fails after the `BasicGet`, the message will be lost.

**Or, with `noAck` false:**

```
var result = channel.BasicGet(queue, false);
// Process the message here ... e.g. save to DB
// If the processing succeeds, Ack to remove the message
channel.BasicAck(result.DeliveryTag, false);
```

This second option would be used for important messages, where loss of a message is not an option. If your consuming process crashes and is unable to acknowledge the message, the message is returned to the queue.

Comment: To add to this, the deliverytag is not just some random unsigned long you create, it comes from the eventargs object, so in the case of the official RabbitMQ C# example, acknowledging would be accomplished with `channel.BasicAck(ea.DeliveryTag, false);`